# Формула прибавление java

Tags: j2me, java

```
private class RunTimerTask extends TimerTask
{
    public final void run()
    {
        int time = 0;
        int time1 = 5;
        int time2 = time+time1;
        t.set(1, " "+ ++count + " ",null);
        t.set(3, " "+ time2 + " ",null);
    }
}
```

Есть таймер. Мне нужно по истечению времени добавлять определенную сумму. Этот же кусок кода он просто добавляет 1 так как `++count` как мне сделать, что бы добавлял к примеру цифру 3.

Comment: Эээ... Я пробовал по всякому расставить отсутствующие запятые в вашем тексте, смысл не появляется ни при какой расстановке.

Comment: есть таймер, мне нужно по истечению времени добавлять определенную сумму. этот же кусок кода он просто добавляет 1 так как ++count как мне сделать что бы добавлял к примеру цифру 3.

Comment: Попробуйте `count += 3`.

Comment: он говорит вообще ошибка

Comment: А как именно вы написали? Вы синтаксис языка знаете?

Answer (score 1):

t.set(1, " "+ (count+=3) + " ",null);

полагаю, так не должно выдавать ошибок